# Excel Autofill behaving unexpectedly

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

When designing formula for Excel auto-fill, I find that the program will make unwanted assumptions about the progression of the values.
As Below, I want the following Sample:

> =C3*'Ore info'!C3 | =D3*'Ore info'!C4 | =E3*'Ore info'!C5

To continue auto-fill into the following:

> =F3*'Ore info'!C6 | =G3*'Ore info'!C7 | =H3*'Ore info'!C8

But instead, it will auto-fill as follows:

> =F3*'Ore info'!G3 | =G3*'Ore info'!G4 | =H3*'Ore info'!G5

In other words, the excel sheet is changing values that should be constant (Letters) and repeating values that should progress (numbers).

Is there a process I can follow to get the formulas auto-filling correctly, or will I have to continue manually repairing the values?

Comment: Values that you want to be constant are to be preceded by a `#`.

Comment: @simlev That is probably a typo and you meant `$`, no?

Comment: @Enjgine that is not how Excel works. What direction are you filling? Down or across? Can you describe the logic behind the desired increments, please? Typically, if you fill down, the row number will increase by 1. If you fill across, the column letter shifts by one, unless you use absolute referencing with $ signs. In your case you are shifting row numbers AND column letters. This can be done, but it is more complex than just typing the first formula. So, again, what is your logic in words? Please edit your question and then post a comment that you have done so for people who follow this.

Comment: @teylyn `$` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

$ Before each value that must be constant is correct, thank you. This is a very simple solution I must admit, thanks for the answers.

I.E. I must insert

> =C3*'Ore info'!$C3 | =D3*'Ore info'!$C4 | =E3*'Ore info'!$C5

to keep the letters the same.

Thanks again @simlev @teylyn !